# call to startActivityForResult() from non activity class and getting result in existing activity or fragment

Tags: android, startactivityforresult

My IntentHelper class is

```
public class IntentHelper {

    private Activity activity;

    // Camera activity request code
    public static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    //Gallery activity request code
    public static final int GALLERY_OPEN_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 101;

    public IntentHelper(Activity activity){
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    /**
     * Launching gallery to get image
     */
    public void getGalleryImage(){

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
        intent.putExtra("outputFormat",
                Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());

        activity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"),GALLERY_OPEN_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
```

I am calling this class from fragment as :

```
IntentHelper intentHelper = new IntentHelper(getActivity());
intentHelper.getGalleryImage();
```

My gallery intent is successfully open with this logic.
But :

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // following if condition is not executing
    if(requestCode == IntentHelper.GALLERY_OPEN_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            SnackbarHelper.showSnackBar("Image browsed sucessfully",getView());
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Image browsed successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        else if(requestCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            SnackbarHelper.showSnackBar("Image browsed cancelled",getView());
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why is this happening.
My intent is called perfectly and is returning me to same activity then why this onActivityResult() condition is not working ???

> My all code is in fragment. But I don't think so it cause this problem

**EDIT - SOLUTION**

As answer given by @laalto is true. I have to start startActivityForResult() with fragment instance.

Hence I changed my IntentHelper class as :

```
public class IntentHelper {
/*
* Instead of Activity use Fragment
*/
private Fragment fragment;

// Camera activity request code
public static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
//Gallery activity request code
public static final int GALLERY_OPEN_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 101;

public IntentHelper(Fragment fragment){
    this.fragment = fragment;
}

/**
 * Launching gallery to get image
 */
public void getGalleryImage()  {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    intent.putExtra("scale", true);
    intent.putExtra("outputFormat",
            Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());

    // Use fragment for startActivityForResult() to initiate.
    fragment.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"),GALLERY_OPEN_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

}

IntentHelper is initiated as :

```
IntentHelper intentHelper = new IntentHelper(this);
intentHelper.getGalleryImage();
```

After this changes everything works fine!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My all code is in fragment. But I don't think so it cause this problem

It's the problem.

If you call `Activity#startActivityForResult()`, you receive `onActivityResult` in activity.

If you call `Fragment#startActivityForResult()`, you receive `onActivityResult` in that fragment.

(How this is done under the hood is that `FragmentActivity` encodes a fragment index to the request code for those calls where the result ought to go to a fragment.)

So, calling `startActivityForResult()` in an activity and expecting to see the result in a fragment does not work. Either move the request to fragment, or the response handling to activity.

Also, if you don't handle a result, pass it on to the `super` implementation.

Comment: Thank you !!! I don't need to move my request to fragment or response handling to activity and neither pass it to super implementation, instead just pass fragment to IntentHelper()

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this in your activity's onActivityResult, call super.onActivityResult()

and in fragment
 in your fragment make sure you call

```
startActivityForResult(intent,111); instead of getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent,111); inside your fragment.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call
`super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` in the `onActivityResult()` of the activity that houses the fragment before the fragment itself can receive `onActivityResult()` triggers made. Simply put the following in your Activity:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Pass your fragment to IntentHelper as `IntentHepler(MyFragment fragment)` then instantiate it like `IntentHelper intentHelper = new IntentHelper(this);`, if you need Activity instance inside `IntentHelper`, you may get it using `fragment.getActivity()`. I think it should work that way.