# How to launch activity from non-activity class and receive the onActivityResult() on the activity class

Tags: java, android

I have one class that extends from fragment, and another class, which is a non-activity class that starts some intents (camera related stuff).

I pass the first one to the constructor on the second one so the second one can perform the creation of intents and start them. But I expect that the `onActivityResult` gets called on the activity side, the Fragment, but it never gets called. What I'm doing wrong?

**Fragment class:**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment
{
    private static final String TAG = "Example";
    private NonActivityClass nonActivityClass = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        RequestPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        nonActivityClass = new NonActivityClass(getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "ON RESULT");
        if (requestCode == NonActivityClass.REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "ON RESULT!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Non-activity class:**

```
public class NonActivityClass
{
    private Activity activity;
    static final int REQUEST = 1;

    public NonActivityClass(Activity activity)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
    }
    private Activity getActivity()
    {
        return  this.activity;
    }

    public void DispatchTakePictureIntent()
    {    
        PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        if (packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY))
        {
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

            // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null)
            {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                File photoFile = null;
                try
                {
                    photoFile = CreateImageFile(); //this method creates the temporary file, shouldn't be relevant
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error occurred while creating the File:" + ex.toString());
                }
                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null)
                {
                    Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),
                            "com.example.fileprovider",
                            photoFile);
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);

                    //THIS
                    getActivity().startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST);
                    //
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Even following this answer: [call to startActivityForResult() from non activity class and getting result in existing activity or fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51100518/call-to-startactivityforresult-from-non-activity-class-and-getting-result-in-e)

and instead of pasing the activity passing the fragment, it doesn't call onResult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking close to the answer that I post on my question: [call to startActivityForResult() from non activity class and getting result in existing activity or fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51100518/call-to-startactivityforresult-from-non-activity-class-and-getting-result-in-e)

I've noticed that the problem is that I was calling startActivityForResult() from Activity, and should be called from the fragment. So instead passing Activity to my class, I refractored like the answer to use Fragment.

So fragment code will look like:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment
{
    private static final String TAG = "Example";
    private NonActivityClass nonActivityClass = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        RequestPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        nonActivityClass = new NonActivityClass(this); //this, instead of getActivity()
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "ON RESULT");
        if (requestCode == NonActivityClass.REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "ON RESULT!");
        }
    }
}
```

And non-activity class like:

```
public class NonActivityClass
{
    private Fragment fragment;
    static final int REQUEST = 1;

    public NonActivityClass(Fragment fragment)
    {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }
    private Activity getActivity()
    {
        return  this.fragment.activity;
    }

    public void DispatchTakePictureIntent()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "DISPATCH");

        PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        if (packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY))
        {
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

            // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null)
            {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                File photoFile = null;
                try
                {
                    photoFile = CreateImageFile(); //this method creates the temporary file, shouldn't be relevant
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error occurred while creating the File:" + ex.toString());
                }
                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null)
                {
                    Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),
                            "com.example.fileprovider",
                            photoFile);
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);

                    //THIS
                    fragment.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
                    //
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```